# Is it a coincidence that this actor guest starred in Doctor Who: The Woman Who Lived?

Tags: doctor-who, actors

In *The Woman Who Lived*,

> Struan Rodger guest stars as Ashildr's servant, Clayton.

However, we've seen this actor in Doctor Who before. Specifically, as

> the voice of the Face of Boe.

Given that that character was a bit of an elephant in the room during the episode, enough to warrant an explicit namedrop, was this episode's casting choice deliberate or am I reading too much into it?

This isn't a question about reused actors as much as about whether or not Moffat planted an Easter egg.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is it even possible that Martha became the Doctor's companion?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39511/how-is-it-even-possible-that-martha-became-the-doctors-companion)

Comment: @BESW Does the edit make it better?

Comment: So a good answer would cite some evidence of Moffat's intent, like a statement he made, and not in-universe speculation?

Comment: @BESW Pretty much.

Comment: Then, yes, it's not functionally identical to any of the other "same actor cast in two roles on Doctor Who" questions. I retract my close vote.

Comment: I thought something was up with this character when he used the word 'cocktail' in the 1600s about 150 years too early for that word.

Comment: So, is your theory that this is very-old-Jack nearing the end of his humanity?

Comment: @Neil W - agree, also wasn't it morning, more like breakfast time? (Of course, cocktails for breakfast isn't a BAD thing, it's just not usual!)

Comment: Is it a coincidence that Gimli's actor in LOTR also voices Treebeard? This must be intentional, treebeard is a tree and Gimli wields an axe! Nope, it's just coincidence. His voice worked for Treebeard, ergo his voice was used. There's no in-universe meaning. Especially in long-running shows, actors can be reused to play different characters ([Deadwood did it too](https://www.quora.com/How-could-HBO-allow-Garret-Dillahunt-to-play-two-different-characters-on-Deadwood))