# Is there any story connections between Devor in TNG and Tuvok on Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

In the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode "Starship Mine", there is a character [Devor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Devor), a mercenary, who was played by Tim Russ.

In *Star Trek: Voyager*, there is a character Tuvok, also played by Tim Russ. Did they ever make any story connections between the two?

Note: I found [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31779/any-continuity-between-tim-russs-appearances-in-stgenerations-and-voyager) question but it seems to be about *Star Trek: Generations*, not TNG.

Comment: (Don't tell this guy about Jeffrey Combs!)

Comment: @JohnSensebe http://imgur.com/gallery/ZlgW7nb

Comment: He also played the Spaceball who said "[We ain't found sh*t!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3iFJpGJiug&feature=youtu.be&t=28s)". I believe there's no connection between them and Tuvok.

Comment: @Richard, I disagree. I've watched every episode of *Voyager*, and I do believe Tuvok never found sh!t. Also, Tim Russ replaced a guy who briefly appeared in the movie *Alien Nation*, when it became a series and they expanded on an incident in the movie and couldn't find the original actor. I don't believe that guy had any connection to Tuvok,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No, absolutely no connection whatsoever.

Tuvok is Vulcan. Devor is not.  Completely different species.

[image]

Above: Tim Russ as Devor.

[image]

Above: Tim Russ as Tuvok.  *Notice the ears.*

Also, major plot point:

> Devor was ***killed*** by the baryon sweep at the end of "Starship Mine", two years before Tuvok and Voyager were stranded in the Delta Quadrant.

Comment: There should have been a Voyager episode where a transporter accident sends Tuvok to the Enterprise during the events of "Starship Mine."

Comment: Given that Lore is Data, it's still a valid question.

Comment: @Valorum: What do you mean by that?

Comment: "Also, major plot point:" - a "story connection", as asked for in the question, is not restricted to the two somehow being the very same character. One could have the idea of convoluted explanations such as "Devor was a time-travelling clone of Tuvok sent back after Tuvok had rejoined Starfleet and returned to the Alpha quadrant." (And, **no**, this is *not* mentioned anywhere in canon or fanon, nor is it something I deem likely or would like to see. Gotta make sure I'm not starting a new rumour here.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Lore is Data. It was revealed in one of the short stories that [Lore is actually a time-shifted Data](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Lore#Second_Lore)

Comment: @Praxis - you might wish to note that Devor is not explicitly referred to as being any species other than "humanoid" in the script; https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/244.txt

Comment: Memory alpha thinks he's human, but doesn't offer any specific confirmation. He could be a Vulcan who's had an ear tuck.